# Como enviar datos desde javascript con axios a un controlador MVC de Asp.NETCore

Tags: javascript, c#, axios

Hola tengo el siguiente controlador y modelo en C#:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromBody]ID data) {
            if (data!=null)
            {

            }

            return Ok();
        }



        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }

    public class ID
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

Y tengo el siguiente script javascript en donde estoy intentando capturar un dataset de un div html y enviarlo a el HomeController mediante axios. Lo estoy intentando de esta manera :

```
let id = { "id": e.target.dataset.id }
 
            try {
                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "/Home/Index",
                    data: JSON.stringify(id)
                }).then(resp => alert(resp))
                    .catch(e => alert(e));


            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
```

Sin embargo me devuelve un error con status 415 : "Request failed with status code 415".
Nota: Si yo le quito el atributo [FromBody] al método con el atributo HttpPost entonces si me llega el dato pero me llega null  !!. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tenía que agregar un header para que el controlador soportara el json del request:

```
let id = { "id": e.target.dataset.id }
 
            try {
                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    url: "/home/index",
                    data: JSON.stringify(id)
                }).then(resp => alert(resp))
                    .catch(e => alert(e));


            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
```

Con eso se solucionó!